# What is the missing word

Tags: word-requests

What could be a correct word to replace "x" in the question?

你要换这个东西 "X" 那个吗？
(Do you want to exchange this for that?)

Comment: answer in dictionaries, e.g. feed "exchange for" to jukuu

Comment: E.g. 你要把这个东西换那个吗？

Comment: as in comment #2, X is usually replaced by nothing, but with different position for verb 换, 你要这个东西换那个，cf。jukuu： He gave me an apple in exchange for a cake.
 ３。他给我一个苹果，换一块蛋糕。8.  I'll give you three sweets in exchange for an apple.
 我拿三块糖换你一个苹果。 

换A成／为B， A=这个东西，B＝那个 also possible, （e.g.currency)

Comment: This is not a natural speaking, so I can not find a word for X. It will be better: 你要用这个东西换那个吗?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am come from Taiwan.
我來自台灣
In traditional,If the clerk want to check your request that you want to replace!
They always said:"請問你要把"A"換成"B"嗎?"
傳統上,如果店員要確認你換貨的需求.他們會說:"請問你要把"A"換成"B"嗎?"

Do you want to exchange this for that?
(你想要把這個東西和那個東西(交換/取代)嗎?)
你要换这个东西 "X" 那个吗？
參考答案:
你要换这个东西 "成為" 那个吗？

Answer (score 1):

For my opinion,i will replace the 'X' with '成',  by not changing the whole sentence...
**你要换这个东西 "成" 那个吗？**
However the sentence I've mentioned sounds weird,we usually say:
你要把这个东西换成那个吗?

Answer (score 0):

weird. If you want to exchange this for that, should be "你要用这个东西换那个吗"。
If you use "你要换这个东西(A) *和* 那个(B)吗", sounds you want to exchange A+B with something else.

Comment: thank you, 
the context could be,
I bought a T shirt that does not fit me, I a go to speak with the seller, and he propose me to exchange it for another one.

Comment: @ChristopheDebove One way to say it might be 你要把这个东西换成那个吗？（Do you intend/want to exchange this thing for that?）

Comment: jukuu "exchange A for B"  ->  5 example sentences,e.g. 2.  exchange A for B; switch A for B;change A for B
 把a换成b

Comment: @ChristopheDebove What's the original sentence verbatim? It would be weird to call clothes 东西 even in colloquial language.

Comment: @NS.X. Defenitly agree with you. I should be very rare to use 东西 for clothes. but it was just an exemple to respond the a generic issue. In my question I use 东西 to insist in that point. In my comment above I just ilustrated in which situation this interogative structure could be used.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit awkward, but it's still valid to say
你要换这个东西跟那个吗？
Another way to say it 
你要把这个东西换成那个吗？
Or
你要把这个东西跟那个换一下吗？

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to say this would be thus:

"你要把這個東西跟那個換[ 掉] 嗎？“

If you insist on not using the "把“ construction, then you should write it thus:

“你這個東西要換那個嗎？”

Comment: for examples of use of coverb 跟 with verb 换 (for with whom exchange occurs) cf。jukuu：你愿意跟我换一下地方吗? 大卫，我给你的盘子错了，你跟爸爸换一下好吗？ 我十分愉快--这种幸福我跟谁都不换.